# How to merge two files into single file using ansible in remote server

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-playbook, copy, jinja2

I need to merge two files without duplicate entries in it. is there any way i can achieve it through ansible modules.
Ex i have two files /etc/hosts1 and /etc/hosts2. I need to have one /etc/hosts file with all entries present in both /etc/hosts1 and /etc/hosts2 without duplicate entries.
How can i achieve this.
An example would be appreciated

```
- name: Merge two files
  assemble:
    src: /etc/hosts1
    dest: /etc/hosts2
```

The above assemble module fails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works. It reads the contents of all files and reduces the resulting array of lines to unique values. Then a new file with those lines is created.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    hostsfiles:
      - /tmp/hosts1
      - /tmp/hosts2
  tasks:
  - name: read files
    command: awk 1 {{ hostsfiles | join(' ') }}
    register: hosts_contents
  - name: create hosts file
    copy:
      dest: /tmp/hosts
      content: "{{ hosts_contents.stdout_lines | unique |join('\n') }}"
```

I'm using `awk 1` instead of `cat` to add potentially missing line breaks to the end of the source files.

Comment: Any Other way i can achieve this? Since i dont want to create new directory.

Comment: It didn't create the wanted result anyway, since the result still contained duplicate entries. I now posted a working variant.

Comment: These are my entries
 cat /etc/hosts_1
A B C D E F G H I J K
cat /etc/hosts_2
12345678
I followed your command but its not merging or appending to the file.
cat /etc/hosts
A B C D E F G H I J K

Comment: can i merge three files

Comment: read files task gives error when any of the file is not is present. How to avoid that

Comment: If you have follow up questions, you should ask new questions for them. Provide your playbook in the state it currently is, so someone can give you a matching answer.